# mysqli_fetch_assoc loop inside of another mysqli_fetch_assoc loop

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops

I've been searching the internet for a while trying to find this answer, but perhaps my search topics are just not right. I have an SQL query that returns the data from two tables into a combined results set. I want to loop through and find each "section" and print it out, and underneath each "section" I want to print out the events associated with that section. I basically have a parent loop to look for the "sections" and a child loop inside of the parent loop to search for events. My code is below.

Can anyone explain why the parent loop only iterates 1 time and then stops? I'd sure appreciate it!

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if($row['ID'] != "") {
      echo '<h3 class="classTlt">'.$row['sTitle'].'</h3>';
      echo $row['sDesc']; 
      $table = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>';
      for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++) {
         if($row['sH'.$i] != null) {
           $table .= '<th>'.$row['sH'.$i].'</th>';
         }
      }
      $table .= '</tr>';
      while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row2['sID'] == $row['ID']) {
          $table .= '<tr>';
          for($x=1;$x<=6;$x++) {
             if($row2['sV'.$x] != null) {
                 $table .= '<td valign="top">'.$row2['sV'.$x].'</td>';
             }//end if
          }//end for
          $table .= '</tr>';
        }//end if
      }//end while
      $table .= '</table>';
      echo $table; 
  }//end if
}//end while
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You drain the result set dry within the inner loop.

If your result has 10 rows, the outer while extracts 1, the inner extracts the other 9 and the outer has nothing to extract any more.

Edit:
in respect of the comments:

```
$someArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $someArray[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($someArray); ++$i) {
  // some stuff

  for($j = 0; $j < count($someArray); ++$j) {
    // some more stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: @scones - so how would I prevent this? Sorry, I'm still learning PHP.

Comment: @scones - Actually, with the child loop, I want to start at the very beginning of the results set, not at record #2. So how would I be able to use my results set for both loops?

Comment: You can load all the data into an array before rendering the contents. after that you can iterate over the array using `for($i = 0; $i < count($someArray); ++$i)` and another variable name in the inner loop.

Comment: @scones - I think I understand. I'll give it a try and post back in a few minutes.

Comment: @scones - Your solution worked beautifully! I used a foreach loop as my parent and child since I already had a couple of nested for loops, but it worked the same. Just for clarification: are these the only solutions to this kind of scenario? (1)Use separate queries, and therefore, separate result sets; (2)Drop the combined result set into an array for iterating through nested loops.

Comment: @Leann this scenario is highly unusual. It suggests the possibility of improvements on the data structure. I would assume you use one table to hold the data, while you should use two tables, which represent the specific data sets. But that would be a new topic/question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this easy ad simple method :

```
$sql = "SELECT id_customer , firstname ,email 
FROM ps_customer limit 20";

$customers = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($customers,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for ($i=0; $i < count($rows); $i++) { 
    echo $rows[$i]["id_customer"] . " " . $rows[$i]["email"] . "<br>";
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner `while` loop is hitting the same `$result` variable, and thus depleting the available rows to iterate.

You would be best served to have two queries:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       // some logic / display code

       $result2 = ... // sql query w/ section data

       while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
          // more logic / display code
       }
    }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that it was best practice to reduce the number of queries to the database as much as possible to avoid lengthy page load times. Of course, there are some scenarios where more than one query is required, but I found that I could make one query in this case. What is considered best practice?

Comment: If you know the number of rows, i.e. Row 0 is a header, and 5 rows will always be sub-rows, then Row 6 will be a header, etc., then @scones solution will work.

Good practice, yes, reduce queries. But how many queries are we talking about? How big is the data set? If the data set isn't going to get bloated, and you're not writing a high-volume application, then the two queries are easier to understand and easier to read, and thus the better implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this. As part of learning, I still need to find more documentation on which approaches are best in certain scenarios. I appreciate your advice!!